# Set the cursor to WaitCursor with PowerShell and WPF GUI

Tags: wpf, powershell

If I use a regular windows form in PowerShell using this works.

```
$Form.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::WaitCursor
```

How can I achieve the same when dealing with a WPF application in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property name on WPF elements is the same ([`Cursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.cursor)).

Assign one of the static member values from the [`[System.Windows.Input.Cursors]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.cursors):

```
$wpfElement.Cursor = [System.Windows.Input.Cursors]::Wait
```

Comment: Thanks, I was sure that was something I tried in my many attempts to do this. `$Form.Cursor = [System.Windows.Input.Cursors]::Arrow` then to reset.